# How to backup and access jbpm 7.3 maven artifactory and git repository

Tags: drools, jbpm

We want use **JBPM 7.3** for business rules development and testing. However for execution we will execute kie-base in our application, which is in java. For this we require access to JBPM maven repository.

1. How to fetch kjar from jbpm maven repository in my development environment using pom.xml. I mean, can i access jbpm **7.3** maven repository, if yes what is repository url.
2. JBPM **7.3** doesn't provide backup option for git repository and maven artifactory. Is there any recommendation, if yes. how to setup that Or it is not require, JBPM will auto take care of this. ( JBPM doesn't provide any setting option for maven and git repo.)

Please let me know, if more detail require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This section](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#test-scenarios-running-locally-proc) of the official documentation shows you how to clone a project from the Kie Workbench into your local environment and to run some tests using maven. It also shows you how to get the repository's URL.

As you can see, each project in the Kie Workbench belongs to a single maven repository containing a maven project inside.

As far as I know, there is no automatic backup feature. There is [another part](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_wb.vfsclustering) of the documentation that explains how to configure a VFS Cluster. You can use this as a way of keeping 2 git repositories in sync. But that is probably too much work. For a simple backup mechanism you can create a CRON job that keeps a backup repository always in sync with the repository in your Kie Workbench.

Hope it helps,